# How to define function with arbitrary precision (Eigen/MPRealSupport)

Tags: c++, eigen, mpfr

How to define `Matrix<mpreal, Dynamic, Dynamic>` with `typedef`?

We usually put the defined type in a header file, but it needs `mpreal::set_default_prec(256);` and that's the problem.

I am quite new to MPFR, so my apology if it seems easy.
So what is your idea?

```cpp
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "mylibrary.hpp"
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MPRealSupport>

using namespace mpfr;
using namespace Eigen;


MatrixXmp hilbert_matrix(const int size)
{
    MatrixXmp A = MatrixXmp::Zero(size, size);
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; ++i)
        for (int j = 1; j < size + 1; ++j)
            A(i - 1, j - 1) = 1. / (i + j - 1.);

    return A;
}


int main()
{
    // set precision to 256 bits (double has only 53 bits)

    mpreal::set_default_prec(256);
    typedef Matrix<mpreal, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXmp;
    typedef Matrix<mpreal, Dynamic, 1> VectorXmp;
    

    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```sh
‘MatrixXmp’ does not name a type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpreal` (attention, it is located inside a namespace `mpfr`) is a class and [`set_default_prec` is a `static` method](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/unsupported/test/mpreal/mpreal.h). This means that setting the precision has no effect on the template parameter and therefore also not on the `typedef`. Calling the `static` function will change the default precision only internally without having effects on the template.

- You can **`typedef`** outside of your main inside your **header** and only then **set the precision inside the `main` of the program** which calls it.

  ```
   using MatrixXmp = Matrix<mpfr::mpreal, Dynamic, Dynamic>;
   using VectorXmp = Matrix<mpfr::mpreal, Dynamic, 1>;

   int main() {
     mpfr::mpreal::set_default_prec(256);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
  ```
- Alternatively there is a constructor

  ```
  mpreal(const mpz_t u, mp_prec_t prec = mpreal::get_default_prec(), mp_rnd_t mode = mpreal::get_default_rnd());
  ```

  This means you could actually **add a `mp_prec_t prec` as a (template) argument to your function and default it to `256`**. Then when constructing any sort of `mpfr::mpreal` pass the precision and potentially also the rounding policy as second and third argument to the constructor.

Comment: `typedef Matrix<mpreal, Dynamic, Dynamic> MatrixXmp;` what is `mpreal` in header file? It will give not defined error, right?

Comment: @Abolfazl No, it should not. Be sure to add `using namespace mpfr;` as it is `mpfr::mreal`. It is inside the `mpfr` namespace!